# NestJS Logger Doesn't Print on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am using the [NestJS starter](https://github.com/nestjs/typescript-starter.git) from their documentation [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/#alternatives).

- NestJS 7.6.15.
- Node Version 12.20.1
- Windows 10 Pro (OS Build 19042.867)

I did not change anything in the main.ts to change the logger functionality.

**main.ts:**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

None of my loggers are printing anything at all. Example:

```
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, CronExpression } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Injectable()
export class ScheduledTask {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(ScheduledTask.name);

  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_5_SECONDS)
  handleCron() {
    this.logger.log('This does not print.');
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nest-typescript-starter",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nest TypeScript starter repository",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^0.4.3",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.31"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.6.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.3.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.15",
    "@types/cron": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.36",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.18",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like NestJS doesn't automatically rebuild my **dist** folder. Once I deleted that manually it forced a rebuild and the logs started displaying. Seems like I need to do this every time I change code.

Comment: using the `--watch` flag should rebuild upon changes. Also you could add `"deleteOutDir": true` in your `nest-cli.json` under `"compilerOptions"` entry and then nest build will delete the `dist` folder before